# Macro to Reset the table thank you

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/khvqO.jpg]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim dccolumn As Integer
Dim dcvalue As String

dccolumn = ActiveCell.Column
dcvalue = ActiveCell.Value

If Application.Intersect(ActiveCell, [headers]) Is Nothing Then

        If ActiveCell.Value <> "" Then

         Me.ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter Field:=dccolumn + 2, Criteria1:=dcvalue

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question / problem? ? What it's currently doing, what it should do instead?